# mongoid returns document not found even if its present + tire + mongoid

Tags: mongoid, tire

I m using tire and mongoid in a rails 4 application.

```
class Agent
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Taggable
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  ...
  mapping do
    indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :name, type: 'string', analyzer: 'pattern'
    indexes :tags_array, type: 'string', analyzer: 'pattern'
  end
  ...
  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do
      query do
        string "name:#{params}"
        string "tags_array:#{params}"
      end
    end
  end
  ...
```

There are 4 agents as

```
Agent.all.collect(&:tags)
  => ["pune", "pune", "press", "pune press"] 
Agent.all.collect(&:name)
  => ["agent smith", "first", "second", "third"]
```

I have 3 issues as

1) the first problem is that the agent is not searchable by 'name'.

```
results = Agent.search('first')
  => #<Tire::Results::Collection:0xb26dc4c @response={"took"=>1, "timed_out"=>false, "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0}, "hits"=>{"total"=>0, "max_score"=>nil, "hits"=>[]}}, @options={:load=>true, :size=>10}, @time=1, @total=0, @facets=nil, @max_score=0.0, @wrapper=Tire::Results::Item> 
results.results
  => []
```

2) the second problem is that the mongoid gives error specifying that the object with specified ids dont exist. If i search based on tag

```
results = Agent.search('press')
  => #<Tire::Results::Collection:0xb296da4 @response={"took"=>1, "timed_out"=>false, "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0}, "hits"=>{"total"=>2, "max_score"=>0.30685282, "hits"=>[{"_index"=>"agents", "_type"=>"agent", "_id"=>"{\"$oid\"=>\"521da715f94adc957d000005\"}", "_score"=>0.30685282, "_source"=>{"name"=>"second", "tags_array"=>["press"]}}, {"_index"=>"agents", "_type"=>"agent", "_id"=>"{\"$oid\"=>\"521da715f94adc957d000004\"}", "_score"=>0.19178301, "_source"=>{"name"=>"third", "tags_array"=>["pune press"]}}]}}, @options={:load=>true, :size=>10}, @time=1, @total=2, @facets=nil, @max_score=0.30685282, @wrapper=Tire::Results::Item> 

results.results
  Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound: 
  Problem:
    Document(s) not found for class Agent with id(s) {"$oid"=>"521da715f94adc957d000005"}, {"$oid"=>"521da715f94adc957d000004"}.
  Summary:
    When calling Agent.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): {"$oid"=>"521da715f94adc957d000005"}, {"$oid"=>"521da715f94adc957d000004"} ... (2 total) and the following ids were not found: {"$oid"=>"521da715f94adc957d000005"}, {"$oid"=>"521da715f94adc957d000004"}.

Agent.all.collect(&:id) 
  => ["521da715f94adc957d000007", "521da715f94adc957d000006", "521da715f94adc957d000005", "521da715f94adc957d000004"]
```

3) If i reindex the Agent objects, the ids in the elastic search are entirely different than the mongodb object ids

```
Agent.index_name
  => "agents" 
Tire.index('agents').delete
  => true 
Agent.import
  => #<Tire::Model::Import::Strategy::Mongoid:0xb2dad9c @klass=Agent, @options={:per_page=>1000}, @index=#<Tire::Index:0xb2dabe4 @name="agents", @response=#<Tire::HTTP::Response:0xb30c4b4 @body="{\"took\":630,\"items\":[{\"create\":{\"_index\":\"agents\",\"_type\":\"agent\",\"_id\":\"h0k78SupT9GGTT3I6qV3Bw\",\"_version\":1,\"ok\":true}},{\"create\":{\"_index\":\"agents\",\"_type\":\"agent\",\"_id\":\"LuJMwJSFRquezRUc1HUpEg\",\"_version\":1,\"ok\":true}},{\"create\":{\"_index\":\"agents\",\"_type\":\"agent\",\"_id\":\"gE6MreF8T4ePdD8lqutSJQ\",\"_version\":1,\"ok\":true}},{\"create\":{\"_index\":\"agents\",\"_type\":\"agent\",\"_id\":\"4azbinLjSO2LuRXn9-WYtg\",\"_version\":1,\"ok\":true}}]}", @code=200, @headers={:content_type=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8", :content_length=>"426"}>>> 

results = Agent.search('press')
  => #<Tire::Results::Collection:0xb31bcac @response={"took"=>5, "timed_out"=>false, "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0}, "hits"=>{"total"=>2, "max_score"=>1.0, "hits"=>[{"_index"=>"agents", "_type"=>"agent", "_id"=>"gE6MreF8T4ePdD8lqutSJQ", "_score"=>1.0, "_source"=>{"name"=>"second", "tags_array"=>["press"]}}, {"_index"=>"agents", "_type"=>"agent", "_id"=>"4azbinLjSO2LuRXn9-WYtg", "_score"=>0.19178301, "_source"=>{"name"=>"third", "tags_array"=>["pune press"]}}]}}, @options={:load=>true, :size=>10}, @time=5, @total=2, @facets=nil, @max_score=1.0, @wrapper=Tire::Results::Item> 
results.results
  =>Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound: 
    Problem:
      Document(s) not found for class Agent with id(s) gE6MreF8T4ePdD8lqutSJQ, 4azbinLjSO2LuRXn9-WYtg.
```

Have i defined the mapping correctly? the user should be able to search based on agent name or/and tags. partial name should also be allowed.

==UPDATE

mapping from elasticsearch as a result of localhost:9200/_mapping?pretty=1

```
"agents" : {
  "agent" : {
    "properties" : {
      "id" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "omit_norms" : true,
        "index_options" : "docs"
      },
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "tags_array" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching a solution for the above problems for the last 2 days. Finally, found the solution at https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/775.

Explanation of the problem and solution

```
> Agent.all.collect(&:name)
  => ["first", "second", "third", "agent smith"] 

> Agent.all.collect(&:id)
  => ["52204be3f94adc86b2000007", "52204be3f94adc86b2000006", "52204be3f94adc86b2000005", "52204be3f94adc86b2000004"] 

> Agent.all.collect(&:tags)
  => ["press pune", "press", "pune", "matrix"] 

$ a = Agent.search('pu')
=> #<Tire::Results::Collection:0xbb24cf0 @response={"took"=>1, "timed_out"=>false, "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0}, "hits"=>{"total"=>2, "max_score"=>0.5, "hits"=>[{"_index"=>"agents", "_type"=>"agent", "_id"=>"{\"$oid\"=>\"52204be3f94adc86b2000005\"}", "_score"=>0.5, "_source"=>{"name"=>"third", "tags_array"=>["pune"]}}, {"_index"=>"agents", "_type"=>"agent", "_id"=>"{\"$oid\"=>\"52204be3f94adc86b2000007\"}", "_score"=>0.5, "_source"=>{"name"=>"first", "tags_array"=>["press pune"]}}]}}, @options={:load=>true, :size=>10}, @time=1, @total=2, @facets=nil, @max_score=0.5, @wrapper=Tire::Results::Item> 

2 results present for the above search.

$ a.results
=>
  Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound: 
Problem:
 Document(s) not found for class Agent with id(s) {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000005"}, {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000007"}.

 Summary:
   When calling Agent.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000005"}, {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000007"} ... (2 total) and the following ids were not found: {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000005"}, {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000007"}.
 Resolution:
   Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.
    ....
from /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mongoid-85e146637503/lib/mongoid/findable.rb:88:in `find'
from /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/results/collection.rb:156:in `__find_records_by_ids'
    ....
from /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/results/collection.rb:144:in `block in __get_results_with_load'
from /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/results/collection.rb:131:in `each'
from /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/results/collection.rb:131:in `__get_results_with_load'
from /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/results/collection.rb:27:in `results'
from (irb):2


# method used in tire to retrieve the objects based on the id(s). id or array of ids. 
def __find_records_by_ids(klass, ids)
  @options[:load] === true ? klass.find(ids) : klass.find(ids, @options[:load])
end
```

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
the mongoid 4 changelog specifies that

```
#2497 Calling to_json no longer tampers with the return value from the driver, and proper returns{ "$oid" : object_id.to_s } instead of just the string representation previously
```

Tire expected an array of ids but got an hash as ids: {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000005"}, {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000007"} and tried to find the object as

```
Agent.find({"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000005"}, {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000007"}) #and hence the error.
```

Below code works:

```
Agent.find("52204be3f94adc86b2000004", "52204be3f94adc86b2000007")   
Agent.find(["52204be3f94adc86b2000004", "52204be3f94adc86b2000007"])

Agent.all.collect(&:name).as_json
 => ["first", "second", "third", "agent smith"] 

Agent.all.collect(&:id).as_json
 => [{"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000007"}, {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000006"}, {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000005"}, {"$oid"=>"52204be3f94adc86b2000004"}]
```

the temporary hack: add a initializer with below content

```
require "tire"
module Tire
 class Index
   def get_id_from_document(document) #document is the object. ie agent object in the above case
     case 
       when document.is_a?(Hash)
         document[:_id] || document['_id'] || document[:id] || document['id']
      #if is not an hash and responds to 'id' and object_id is not equal to id "Agent.last.object_id => 96643940"
       when document.respond_to?(:id) && document.id != document.object_id
         document.id.to_s   # was document.id.as_json
       end
     end
   end
end
```